# Codeigniter multiple database connect slow

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

In one of my codeigniter project I want to connect multiple databases. I connected to multiple and its working fine.

Its a renewal - big project. Means need to restructure and fetch data from multiple databases etc.

Since its big, its existing database query as follows

model.php

```
    $res=mysql_query("select * from news order by date DESC LIMIT 0,10");
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
          echo '<li><div class="newshead"><a href="'.site_url('movie-news/'.$r['id'].'/'.$r['seo']).'">'.$r['heading'].'</a></div><img alt="'.$r['heading'].'" align="left" src="share/news/'.$r['thumb'].'" /><p>'.stripslashes(strip_tags(substr($r['news'],0,150))).'</p><br/> <a class="readmore" href="'.site_url('movie-news/'.$r['id'].'/'.$r['seo']).'">Read More</a></li>';
         }
```

So I added 2 database in config and connected to db like this

```
    $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
    $res=mysql_query("select * from news order by date DESC LIMIT 0,10");
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
             echo '<li><div class="newshead"><a href="'.site_url('movie-news/'.$r['id'].'/'.$r['seo']).'">'.$r['heading'].'</a></div><img alt="'.$r['heading'].'" align="left" src="share/news/'.$r['thumb'].'" /><p>'.stripslashes(strip_tags(substr($r['news'],0,150))).'</p><br/> <a class="readmore" href="'.site_url('movie-news/'.$r['id'].'/'.$r['seo']).'">Read More</a></li>';
    }
```

Got hundreds of function like this query. My Actual question is insted of adding / connecting database in constructor, I added the database to each function. From there it will get informed to fetch data from which database.

Will it affect the performance of the site ( if I connected to DB from each function )

Actually I coded like this

```
Class Tickets extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->db =$this->load->database('users', TRUE);
         $this->gen = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
    }


function getSlidingThumb(){
    $this->gen->select('*');
    $this->gen->from('front_slide');
    $this->gen->order_by("id", "ASC");
    $query = $this->gen->get();
    $thumbs = $query->result();

    foreach($thumbs as $thu){
       echo '<li><a href="javascript:;"><img  src="share/home/t-'.$thu->image.'" alt="'.$thu->title.'" width="45" height="23" border="0"/></a> </li>'; 

    }
  }
```

In this case I need to connect db to once once in constructor and query like this. $query = $this->gen->get();

But for this I need to edit 100's of existing functions

Please advice me which option I wanna prefer. Client need performance and fast loading

Comment: A model is not supposed to output data, it should return data to the controller which then should pass it to the view. See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you configure your databases so the default user configured in CodeIgniter can access all of them? If yes, you can pass the database as a parameter and use it in your query :

Modify your model :

```
Class Tickets extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getSlidingThumb ($db = 'default') {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from("$db.front_slide");
        $this->db->order_by("id", "ASC");
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();

    }
}
```

For clarity and to respect the MVC pattern, move the HTML to a view :

```
<?php foreach ($thumbs as $thu) : ?>
    <li><a href=""><img src="share/home/t-<?php echo $thu->image;?>" alt="<?php echo $thu->title;?>" width="45" height="23" border="0" /></a></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```